# Software to Capture Data from External Customers

Tags: web-apps

I am working with a client who wants to send order information to one of their clients through email, where the client can accept or deny the order.  Additionally, there are different required fields based on the option.  Ideally, I am hoping there is a product that can allow them to do this, versus creating a website to direct the client to or some other hybrid solution.  Any thoughts or recommendations would be appreciated.

Wade

Comment: I don't see a vote to close option, probably because this has been bumped to the homepage, but I would certainly vote to close as "unclear what you are asking". This is way too broad to be answerable. Please read [ask]. GIGO

Answer (score 1):

If it is to be sent in email, your only choice is a HTML email and hope that the client uses somethign that displays the HTML version by default (I don't... but I admit to being an edge case at times in regards to software)

Assuming that the recipient can indeed view the HTML mail by default, javascript, external scripts, and external resources - images, etc - are typically disabled by default or removed by the displaying webmail system or mail client.

So... assuming you get past the spam filters, assuming your message is viewed as designed, your only real choice is basic HTML 3.2 text and forms with nothing dynamic, and they should POST via HTTPS to a processing script on your end.